# Error Creating Control - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I wrote this code:

```
#region Web Form Designer generated code
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

and I get error:

> Error Creating Control - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I saw that blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2010/05/06/another-error-creating-control-in-the-design-view-with-object-reference-not-set-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You wrote that code? `#region Web Form Designer generated code`

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that Exception *originated* from the code you posted.  If `OnInit` is aprt of the stack trace, then the exception *has* to have been thrown from (or passed through) `InitializeComponent` or `base.OnInit(e)`

Run it in the debugger and see where the exception *actually* originates.  You can also turn on "break on handled exception" if you want, but you'll likely get some false positives.